# org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 for postgres spring data jpa

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.4

Below are my tables i am using PostgreSQL with spring data jpa

```
public class Person 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "person_id" )
    private Long personId;
    private String givenName;
}

public class Address 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column( name = "address_id" )
    private Long addressId;

@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn( name = "person_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey( name = "fk_person_person_id" ) )
    Person person;
    private String Address;
}
```

Below is my native query

```
 User.getAllUsersWithAddress=select to_json(p.*) AS person,to_json(a.*) AS Address from person p INNER JOIN address a ON p.person_id=a.person_id

@Query( nativeQuery = true )
List<Object[]> getAllUsersWithAddress( );
```

But the query is throwing exception 
 Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 for postgres.
even though i added below code added

```
public class PostgreSQLDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect
{
    public PostgreSQLDialect()
    {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType( Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "json" );
    }
}
```

correct me if anything more to be added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111)

Comment: thanks reply @LaurenzAlbe  i already checked that link it didn't help in my case

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? The "duplicate" question's answers are also useless in my case.