# Spring Data JPA query to select all value from one join table

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have problem to select all value from one table and few other columns using Spring Data JPA. I am using PostgreSql database and when I send query through PgAdmin I get values I want, but if I use it in Spring Boot Rest returns only one table values (subquery not working). What I am doing wrong?

```
@Query(value = "SELECT item.*, MIN(myBid.bid) AS myBid, (SELECT MIN(lowestBid.bid) AS lowestbid FROM bids lowestBid WHERE lowestBid.item_id = item.item_id GROUP BY lowestBid.item_id) FROM item JOIN bids myBid ON item.item_id = myBid.item_id WHERE myBid.user_id = :user_id GROUP BY item.item_id", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Item> findAllWithDescriptionQuery(@Param("user_id") UUID userId);
```

Added Item class

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "item")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID itemId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "title")
    @Size(max = 255)
    private String title;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created_user_id")
    private UUID createdUserId;
}
```

Comment: What is the Item class looking like?

Comment: @PhilippMerkle, I have added Item class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from your native query cannot simply be mapped to entities due to the in-database aggregation performed to calculate the MIN of own bids, and the MIN of other bids. In particular, your `Item` entity doesn't carry any attributes to hold `myBid` or `lowestbid`.

**What you want to return from the query method is therefore a [Projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections).** A projection is a mere interface with getter methods matching exactly the fields returned by your query:

```
public interface BidSummary {

  UUID getItem_id();

  String getTitle();

  String getDescription();

  double getMyBid();

  double getLowestbid();

}
```

Notice how the query method returns the `BidSummary` projection:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT item.*, MIN(myBid.bid) AS myBid, (SELECT MIN(lowestBid.bid) AS lowestbid FROM bids lowestBid WHERE lowestBid.item_id = item.item_id GROUP BY lowestBid.item_id) FROM item JOIN bids myBid ON item.item_id = myBid.item_id WHERE myBid.user_id = :user_id GROUP BY item.item_id", nativeQuery = true)
public List<BidSummary> findOwnBids(@Param("user_id") UUID userId);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I write a Projection in my Item class or ItemRepository?

Comment: The ``BidSummary`` interface could be placed next to your ``Item`` entity, i.e. in the same package. The corresponding query method can be placed in any JPA repository, like the ``ItemRepository``. The ``BidsRepository``, however, appears to be better suited.

Comment: Do I need to use some kind of annotations?

Comment: I am getting this error: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: The error is because Hibernate doesn't know how to map UUIDs to a Postgres data type. See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28193142/7492402

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Everything works as I need. I accept you answer. Thank you again for help.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Return type is List of Item objects and the query specified is having columns which are not part of return object. I recommend using appropriate Entity which full-fills your response type.

Comment: Maybe you could show example how to join two tables with matching ids in both tables by using Entity. Because I couldn't make this join.