# Interface Projection in SpringBoot / Hibernate for an Enum

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I am trying to use Hibernate native queries to select a single column from the database. The column type is an enumeration.

**Java**

```
public interface TicketSummary {

    TicketStatus getSummary();
}

@Repository
public interface TicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, TicketIdentity> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT status AS summary FROM ticket_service.ticket WHERE entitlement_id IN (:entitlementId)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<TicketSummary> findAllTicketsStatusSummary(UUID[] entitlementId);
}
```

**SQL**

```
CREATE TYPE ticket_service.ticket_state AS ENUM( 
    'CREATED',
    'IN_PROGRESS',
    'BLOCKED',
    'CLOSED',
    'COMPLETED'
);
```

I continuously get the following error when querying.

```
exception captured: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

**Debugging**

Placing a breakpoint inside JdbcResultMetadata.getHibernateType displays the following

[image]

Kindly assist me in finding a solution to the same. Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111/30562066

Comment: I'm guessing `TicketStatus` is an enum. How are you mapping it in the `Ticket` entity? Is it working properly for the entity?

Comment: @drkblog Yes if I use the Ticket pojo it correctly maps to the TicketStstus enum. Following are the annotations used

Comment: @NotNull
 @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
 @Type(type = "pgsql_enum")
 private TicketStatus status;