# Calling postgres stored procedure from spring boot

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, stored-procedures

I want to execute postgres stored procedure from my spring boot app.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION procedure_name() RETURNS void language plpgsql
as
$$
BEGIN
// logic implementation is doing manipulation on different tables columns and different database schema.
END
$$
```

This procedure is executing properly from pdAdmin but when I am trying to call it via spring boot app like below-

```
public interface ModelRepository extends JpaRepository<Model, Integer> {
@Query(value = "select public.procedure_name()", nativeQuery = true)
void procedure_name();
}
```

```
Error -

**Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111**
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDia.lect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551) ~[spring-orm-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.10.jar:5.3.10]
```

I know I am doing something wrong. JPARepository needs entity to map but since this procedure function is performing operation on multiple tables and schema and returning VOID so entity is optional.

Is my understanding correct?

Can we have a generic repository? Any examples?

Is there any another way to call this procedure function with or without JPARepository ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111/30562066

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111)