# No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 on a Spring JPA Application and Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a query like this:

```
with t1 as
( select c.id cv_id, age(end_date, start_date) experience_year from cv c 
join candidate ca on c.candidate_id = ca.id 
left join work_experience we on c.id = we.cv_id 
left join major_level ml on c.id = ml.cv_id 
where (ca.address like concat('%',:candidateAddress,'%') or :candidateAddress is null or :candidateAddress = '') 
and ml.major_id in (select m.id from major m where m.major_name like concat('%',:techStack,'%'))) 
select t1.cv_id cvId, sum(experience_year) sumExperienceYear from t1  
group by cv_id 
having ((extract(year from sum(experience_year))) < :experienceYearSearch1 and :experienceOption = 1) 
or ((extract(year from sum(experience_year))) >= :experienceYearSearch1   
and (extract(year from sum(experience_year))) < :experienceYearSearch2 and :experienceOption = 2) 
or ((extract(year from sum(experience_year))) >= :experienceYearSearch2 and :experienceOption = 3) 
or :experienceOption = 0
```

I use Java8 and my properties like this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

This is my Entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "cv")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CV {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "summary")
    private String summary;
}
```

Finally, I got the error code:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
```

Comment: Try to use : `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect` instead of `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`

Comment: @QuentinGenet: does hibernate really not support a more recent (and supported) Postgres version?

Comment: it doesn't working

Comment: PostgreSQL 13.7 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit

Comment: Can you show from your application.properties your drivers JDBC line please ?

Comment: I dont know drivers JDBC config. Can you guide me ?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111). 1111 is Types.OTHER, so please provide the PostgreSQL column types involved in the query (e.g. by providing us the DDL).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `spring.jpa.database-platform` property? This will let hibernate select the most appropriate dialect for the database (at least in the most recent versions). Else check the duplicate as mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 0):

```
org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

is deprecated.

Try to use

```
 org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

instead the deprecated version. Maybe you should change version with your PostgreSQL version...
You should use the dialect that best matches the PostgreSQL JDBC driver you are using.

Have you a jdbc driver dependency in your pom.xml like that ? If there is not? After adding the JDBC driver update your maven project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And then in your application properties you must have this line :

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.jdbc.Driver
```

Try it please to see if there is a better result.
You can have a look on this [good tutorial here.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: I still got msg error No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Comment: Which Hibernate version are you using ?

Comment: Hibernate version : 5.6.4.Final

Comment: Please see my answer and try to update your code.

Comment: Hibernate 6.1 uses Jakarta persistence and not Java Persistence and will not work.