org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 when querying with `json_agg`
When i try to run a jpql native query, i get this error everytime , i use this,
     @Query(value = "select nd.activity, coalesce(json_agg(nd.channel), '[]') as channels, nd.description  from" +
            " notification_detail nd where nd.activity = :activity group by nd.activity, nd.description, nd.channel",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<NotificationListDto> fetchAllNotificationOn(String activity);



I suspect there is issue with json_agg, though I'm running Postgres 14. i feel it should work but i'm not getting error .

[2024-08-04 16:54:13] [ERROR]   [http-nio-9090-exec-1] [o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   (175)] >> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111] with root cause
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

Here is my interface that it returns
public interface NotificationListDto {
    String getActivity() ;
    JsonNode getChannels();
    String getDescription();

}


When i try to remove json_agg , it works perfectly ,
    @Query(value = "select nd.activity,  nd.description  from" +
            " notification_detail nd where nd.activity = :activity group by nd.activity, nd.description, nd.channel",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<NotificationListDto> fetchAllNotificationOn(String activity);


I guess there would be any other ways or what problem I'm running for if json_agg not works.
Thank you for your help.
Edit:
I've Temporary solution for this
SELECT nd.activity, COALESCE(string_agg(nd.channel, ', '), '') AS channels, nd.description FROM notification_detail nd GROUP BY nd.activity, nd.description;

In which i would get data of channels in this way Something, something1 but again i've to do split and other things , which i dont want to do.

Please show us your Entity/DTO, the error is likely in there (a @Type-annotation?). I assume you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111

I'm getting it into an interface, i've included, Thank you .

Your question would be cleaner if you removed the stuff about 'Pageable' and 'countQuery', that has nothing to do with the problem I believe.

Hi @julaine , I've updated question to be cleaner.

I think the problem is that even though you use postgres, hibernate does not like you using database-specific stuff unless you explicitly annotate your code to signify you want to do that. So the @Type-annotation is required

You did not just remove the json_agg-function, you fully removed the channels-field from your select. Can you select a json-field into your interface without json_agg?

getting without using json_agg, would not make any point , because i want to get the array of channels that one activity is containing.

It seems there's some confusion about how the GROUP BY clause is used in your query.
You have grouped by nd.activity, nd.description, and nd.channel, which means you are attempting to aggregate by nd.channel but also trying to aggregate it with json_agg(nd.channel). Typically, json_agg(nd.channel) should be used alone if you want to group all channels for the same activity and description.
Corrected Query:
@Query(value = "SELECT nd.activity, COALESCE(json_agg(nd.channel), '[]') AS channels, nd.description " +
               "FROM notification_detail nd " +
               "WHERE nd.activity = :activity " +
               "GROUP BY nd.activity, nd.description",
       nativeQuery = true)

Here i used some fake data to test it , you can check: json_agg

Hi, Thanks for your response, but unfortunately, It works in native sql query, but not inside spring boot giving still same error ```[2024-08-05 09:45:23] [ERROR]   [http-nio-9090-exec-2] [o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   (175)] >> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111] with root cause
``

can you share your entity ?
