Why am I getting SQL MappingException with Hibernate?
This is my SQL query:
select  sum(case when e.BUY_SELL = 'S' then (e.QUANTITY *-1) else e.QUANTITY end ) ,
e.FUND_ID ,
f.FUND_CODE ,
( CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(f.FUND_NAME), 'secret-key-54321') AS CHAR))as FUND_NAME ,
fp.ID ,
fp.PORTFOLIO_CODE ,
fp.PORTFOLIO_NAME ,
f.FUND_CATEGORY 
from equity_buy_sell  e  
inner join fund f on f.ID =e.FUND_ID 
inner join fund_portfolio fp on fp.ID = e.FUND_PORTFOLIO_ID  
where  e.date <='2024-08-28'   
and e.STATUS ='CONFIRMED' 
and e.STOCK_CODE_ID =3611   
group by e.FUND_ID ,e.FUND_PORTFOLIO_ID;

The results come properly with workbench.
( CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(f.FUND_NAME), 'secret-key-54321') AS CHAR))as FUND_NAME is working fine.
But after applying the SQL query with Java code, the query is not working properly. (( CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(f.FUND_NAME), :key) AS CHAR))as FUND_NAME ) is not working.
String sqlQuery = "select  sum(case when e.BUY_SELL = 'S' then (e.QUANTITY *-1) else e.QUANTITY end ) ,
            e.FUND_ID ,f.FUND_CODE ,( CAST(AES_DECRYPT(UNHEX(f.FUND_NAME), :key) AS CHAR))as FUND_NAME ,
            fp.ID ,fp.PORTFOLIO_CODE ,fp.PORTFOLIO_NAME ,f.FUND_CATEGORY" +
                    " from equity_buy_sell  e " +
                    " inner join fund f on f.ID =e.FUND_ID" +
                    " inner join fund_portfolio fp on fp.ID = e.FUND_PORTFOLIO_ID " +
                    " where  e.date <=:date   and e.STATUS =:status and e.STOCK_CODE_ID =:stock  " +
                    " group by e.FUND_ID ,e.FUND_PORTFOLIO_ID";

Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sqlQuery);
query.setParameter("date", tradeDate);
query.setParameter("status", "CONFIRMED");
query.setParameter("stock", stockCodeId);
query.setParameter("key", key); // parameter is coming (secret-key-54321) but it not set to query properly and getting errors.

The error:
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: -1
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.TypeNames.get(TypeNames.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect.getHibernateTypeName(Dialect.java:368)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$Metadata.getHibernateType(CustomLoader.java:559)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader$ScalarResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(CustomLoader.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:224)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2211)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2095)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2090)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:150)
    at com.cal.finnovation.utms.utms.dao.dealing.SplitDao.getAvailableSplitShares(SplitDao.java:248)
    at com.cal.finnovation.utms.utms.model.dealing.SplitModel.createAvailableSplitSharesBeanList(SplitModel.java:301)
    at com.cal.finnovation.utms.utms.action.corporateaction.SplitReceivableAction.getAvailableSplitsQty(SplitReceivableAction.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)

How can I address this problem?

Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192547/no-dialect-mapping-for-jdbc-type-1111
